# Why ef core 2.1 generates multiple select for include

Tags: sql, sql-server, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I have an ef command which is:

```
var project = await _context.Set<Project>().Include(p => p.Controllers).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == pid);
```

and in execution process it generates two select in form of sql:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [p].[Id], [p].[AppKey], [p].[CreateDate], [p].[Name], [p].[Title]
FROM [Project] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[Id] = @__pid_0
ORDER BY [p].[Id]

SELECT [p.Controllers].[Id], [p.Controllers].[CommandTimeout], [p.Controllers].[ContentType], [p.Controllers].[CreateDate], [p.Controllers].[IsActive], [p.Controllers].[IsJsonSerialize], [p.Controllers].[IsTested], [p.Controllers].[Method], [p.Controllers].[Name], [p.Controllers].[ProjectId], [p.Controllers].[Query], [p.Controllers].[Title]
FROM [Controller] AS [p.Controllers]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP(1) [p0].[Id]
    FROM [Project] AS [p0]
    WHERE [p0].[Id] = @__pid_0
    ORDER BY [p0].[Id]
) AS [t] ON [p.Controllers].[ProjectId] = [t].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
```

The question is why two independent sql commands are being generated while the fist one could be skipped?? is there any reason behind that? for me it seems like a bug!

Comment: It's not a bug, but EF Core design decision. Instead of doing single monster union query, they do one query per each collection. It's debatable which approach is better - EF6 uses the former, EF Core - the later. As of *why* - only EF Core team members can answer that.